# Looping through members of a defined concrete type?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, linq-to-sql

I'm doing comparisons across databases (with about 20 fields) and I've defined a concrete type to handle the comparison.

If my comparison fails, I want to loop through the individual items in the catch block and provide the user a list errors.  Below, I've done it manually through the first few variables.  Is there a more efficient way to loop this through all 20 fields?  I started with a foreach (Object objectItem .. but not sure if that's the right way to go.

Any thoughts or much needed guidance?

```
      try { 

        CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(orgs, members, "Error Matching testlist Fields");

          }

        catch
        {
            //OrgID
            var sourceOrgID = orgs.Select(o => o.OrgID);
            var destOrgID = members.Select(o => o.OrgID);
            var errorList1 = sourceOrgID.Except(destOrgID);
            string failedTests = null; 
            failedTests = string.Join("\n", errorList1);
            Assert.IsTrue(0 == failedTests.Length, "The following Org IDs are not contained in the source: \n" + failedTests);

            //DealerCode
            var sourceDealerCode = orgs.Select(o => o.DealerCode);
            var destDealerCode = members.Select(o => o.DealerCode);
            var errorList2 = sourceDealerCode.Except(destDealerCode);
            failedTests = null; 
            failedTests = string.Join("\n", errorList2);
            Assert.IsTrue(0 == failedTests.Length, "The following Dealer Codes are not contained in the source: \n" + failedTests);


            //orgkey
            var sourceOrgKey = orgs.Select(o => o.OrgKey);
            var destOrgKey = members.Select(o => o.OrgKey);
            var errorList3 = sourceOrgKey.Except(destOrgKey);
            failedTests = null; 
            failedTests = string.Join("\n", errorList3);
            Assert.IsTrue(0 == failedTests.Length, "The following Org Keys are not contained in the source: \n" + failedTests);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need reflection to do this:

```
Type type = obj.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    GetColumn(orgList,property.Name); 
}



var names = items.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("prpname").GetValue(x));


public IEnumerable<object> GetColumn(List<Item> items, string columnName)
{
    var values = items.Select(x => 
x.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(x));//u can put your test code heere and you can loop it through object properties
}
```

you can create a list to store rslt and add results to the list else you can write output in logs files

Answer (score 0):

If I haven't misunderstood your question, you could do something like this using shouldly

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void UnitTestExample()
    {
        var orgs = new Organisation
        {
            Ids = new List<int>{ 1,3 },
            DealerCodes = new List<string> { "foo","bar"}
        };

        var members = new Organisation
        {
            Ids = new List<int> { 1,2,3 },
            DealerCodes = new List<string> { "foo", "bar", "buzz" }
        };

        orgs.ShouldSatisfyAllConditions(
            () => orgs.Ids.ShouldBe(members.Ids, ignoreOrder: true),
            () => orgs.DealerCodes.ShouldBe(members.DealerCodes, ignoreOrder: true)
            );
    }
```

The output produced is:

[image]

You would still have to specify every property you want to check inside ShouldSatisfyAllConditions but shouldly does all the heavy lifting around comparing the lists and output the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assume that:

1. `orgs` is a `IQueryable<T1>`
2. `members` is a `IQueryable<T2>`
3. `typeof(T1) == typeof(T2)`

If so, that function could help:

```
private static void CompareRecords<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> orgs, IQueryable<TEntity> members)
{
  var entityType = typeof (TEntity);
  var selectMethod = typeof (Queryable).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Select");
  var exceptMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Except");
  var toArrayMethod = typeof (Enumerable).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "ToArray");

  foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
  {
    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");
    var propExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, property.Name);
    var delegateType = typeof (Func<,>).MakeGenericType(entityType, property.PropertyType);
    var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, propExpr, paramExpr);

    var parameterizedSelectMethod = selectMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType, property.PropertyType);
    var parameterizedExceptMethod = exceptMethod.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType);

    var source = parameterizedSelectMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {orgs, lambdaExpr});
    var dest = parameterizedSelectMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {members, lambdaExpr});

    var errorList = parameterizedExceptMethod.Invoke(null, new[] {source, dest});

    var errorListArray = toArrayMethod.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType).Invoke(null, new[] {errorList});

    var failedTests = string.Join("\n", ((IEnumerable)errorListArray).Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()));
    Assert.IsTrue(0 == failedTests.Length, $"The following {property.Name} are not contained in the source: \n{failedTests}");
  }
}
```